# Replacing values in numpy array based on inequalities

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Given a numpy array, I would like to replace its values based on inequalities. For example, given

```
x=np.array([0.3,7,8,-5.5,1,0.1])
```

I want to replace the values that are smaller than 0 with 0, those that are between 0 and 5 would be replaced by 1, and the rest would be replaced with 2. So I want to get:

```
x=np.array([1,2,2,0,1,1])
```

I could do that with `pandas.cut` as follows:

```
pandas.cut(pandas.DataFrame(x).iloc[:,0],[-np.inf,0,5,np.inf],labels=[0,1,2],right=False)
```

but I was wondering if there is a more direct way to do that using numpy itself. Note that I could have more than 3 categories, which is why I was looking for something more systematic that behaves similarly to `pandas.cut`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perfect setup to leverage [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
np.searchsorted([0,5],x)
```

This is extensible to incorporate generic number of bin elements. Thus, generically put -

```
bins = [0,5]
out = np.searchsorted(bins,x)
```

Sample runs -

```
In [46]: x
Out[46]: array([ 0.3,  7. ,  8. , -5.5,  1. ,  0.1])

In [47]: np.searchsorted([0,5],x)
Out[47]: array([1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1])

In [55]: np.searchsorted([0,2,5],x)
Out[55]: array([1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1])

In [60]: np.searchsorted([0,2,5,7],x)
Out[60]: array([1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `digitize`?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.3,7,8,-5.5,1,0.1]) 
bins = np.array([-np.inf,0,5,np.inf])
np.digitize(x, bins) - 1 # Results are 1-based index
# array([1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```